# More efficient/elegant way of handling this complicated LIKE statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, sql-like

I need some help trying make this `LIKE` statement a little more elegant and efficient. It performs how I'd expect it to, but it's very slow, even on small data sets. I am using SQL-Server 2016 with SSMS 2017 on a win 10 machine. Thanks in advance!

```
where (a.Description like '% ' + @event + ' %'  
        or a.Description like '% ' + @event + '.'   
        or a.Description like '% ' + @event + '.%'  
        or a.Description like '% ' + @event + ',%'  
        or a.Description like '% ' + @event + ';%'
        or a.Description like '%'  + @event + '/%'
        or a.Description like '%/' + @event + '%'
        or a.Description like '% ' + @event 
        or a.Description like @event + ' %' 
        or a.Description like @event 
        )
```

@event is just a `varchar` like 'Death' or 'Tripped'. If you have a better approach, by all means, school me!

Comment: Simplifying this isn't going to help the performance. Your performance issue is because you have a leading wildcard, this make your predicate nonSARGable and it has to scan every single row.

Comment: Thanks @SeanLange I appreciate the input. Can you recommend a more solid approach?

Comment: @StelioK is the `@accident` variable in your query by accident or it's a part of it?

Comment: you can try contains searching on the split up description string

Comment: @Parfait What if there is values he don't want to return them? eg: '@Tripped'

Comment: @Parfait If I am looking for 'hand' that would also return 'handle' etc.. Thanks for the input!

Comment: @DhruvJoshi that is probably the best route but I was just trying to grok it out quick, there are so many type-o's too. Its a one off but I might just have to do that. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think the trailing `%` adds anything - that may offer some speed up?

Comment: @NetMage I didn't think it would either but without that, it wasn't picking up strings like 'Sprained/Twisted'; adding "or a.Description like '%/' + event + '%'" was the only way I could get Twisted out of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

T-SQL supports character classes in `LIKE` so you can simplify:

```
where (a.Description like '%[ /]' + @event + '[ .,;/]%'
        or a.Description like '%[ /]' + @event
        or a.Description like @event + '[ .,;/]%'
        or a.Description like @event 
        )
```

If you are willing to accept any non-alphabetical separators (what about digits) you can do something like:

```
where (a.Description like '%[^a-z0-9]'+@event+'[^a-z0-9]%'
       or a.Description like @event+'[^a-z0-9]%'
       or a.Description like '%[^a-z0-9]'+@event
       or a.Description like @event
       )
```

Comment: Excellent, I am going to try it now.

Comment: You are a legend my friend. Thanks!!! This was the simplification/elegance I was searching for, unfortunately it is significantly slower, but thanks!!!

Comment: This is actually pulling non-matching strings like 'handleman' when I search for 'hand'. Hmmmm.... I think I can probably adjust, let me see.

Comment: Fixed it - I copied from your example, which I think had some typos?

Comment: No Type-os in mine, works fine ;) I'll try it out again, thanks!!

Comment: No dice buddy, same issue. No worries though, I appreciate the help and have accepted your answer.

Comment: I see it looks like yours would accept `/handleman` but not `handleman`.

Comment: Yes, fortunately in this set it is not an issue. I'd like to come up with a black box solution but I just don't have the time at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

One way to make it possibly faster, assuming the description is non-indexed column is to create smaller strings out of the original description string and do the comparisons against these smaller string.

This is good till you have less data in description column.

If you can pre-store and index the stored data column, you can try something dynamic like below

I bench marked and found the performance of like %string% getting bad after N=13

```
if exists (select object_id('t') )
drop table t
create table t (description varchar(max));

insert into t  values
('Implemantion of the CR systems at dealership level for understanding of the customer concern & faster resolution'),
('Trend analysis for Customer Complaint Ratio at Regional / Zonal / Area level both for Sales and Service operations');

declare @counter int
set @counter=1

WHILE @counter<15
begin
insert into t
select * from t
set @counter=@counter+1
end
declare @start datetime,@end1 datetime,@end2 datetime


declare @lookingfor varchar(100)
set @lookingfor ='level'

select 
description,
cast(substring(t.description,N,LEN(@lookingfor)) as varchar(100)) as d into #t from t
outer apply
(select top (select LEN(t.description)-LEN(@lookingfor)+1)
 row_number() over(order by (select null)) N
  from sys.objects s1 cross join sys.objects s2
)T1

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_C_temp_d ON #t(d)

set @start=getdate()
select count(distinct description) from t
where description like '%'+@lookingfor+'%'

select @end1=getdate()

select count(distinct description) from #t  where d like @lookingfor

select @end2=getdate()

select datediff(ss,@start,@end1)

select datediff(ss,@end1,@end2)

select @start,@end1,@end2

drop table #t
```

PS: You will need to benchmark your solution.